# How to pass function argument to boost::async()

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, c++14

How do I get `boost::async` to pass a function argument to the function it executes. My code is

```
#include <iostream>

// This is for the boos version
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
using boost::async;

// This is for the standard library version
//~ #include <future>
//~ using std::async;

int f(int x) {
   std::cout << " in f " << x << std::endl;
   return x+1;
}

int main() {
    auto f_res = async(f,3);
    std::cout << "f " << f_res.get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with

```
g++ -std=c++14 -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lpthread test_async_boost.cc
```

, g++ version 5.3.0 and get many errors, complaining about the number of arguments `async` is willing to take:

```
test_async_boost_2.cc: In function 'int main()':
test_async_boost_2.cc:16:26: error: no matching function for call to 'async(int (&)(int), int)'
    auto f_res = async(f,3);
                          ^
In file included from test_async_boost_2.cc:3:0:
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:4035:3: note: candidate: template<class F> boost::unique_future<typename boost::result_of<F()>::type> boost::async(F&&)
   async(BOOST_THREAD_FWD_REF(F) f) {
   ^
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:4035:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test_async_boost_2.cc:16:26: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
    auto f_res = async(f,3);
                          ^
In file included from test_async_boost_2.cc:3:0:
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:4018:3: note: candidate: template<class R> boost::unique_future<T> boost::async(R (*)())
   async(R(*f)()) {
   ^
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:4018:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test_async_boost_2.cc:16:26: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
    auto f_res = async(f,3);
                          ^
In file included from test_async_boost_2.cc:3:0:
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:3695:3: note: candidate: template<class F> boost::unique_future<typename boost::result_of<typename boost::decay<T>::type()>::type> boost::async(boost::launch, F&&)
   async(launch policy, BOOST_THREAD_FWD_REF(F) f) {
   ^
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:3695:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test_async_boost_2.cc:16:26: note:   cannot convert 'f' (type 'int(int)') to type 'boost::launch'
    auto f_res = async(f,3);
                          ^
In file included from test_async_boost_2.cc:3:0:
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:3634:3: note: candidate: template<class R> boost::unique_future<T> boost::async(boost::launch, R (*)())
   async(launch policy, R(*f)()) {
   ^
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:3634:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test_async_boost_2.cc:16:26: note:   cannot convert 'f' (type 'int(int)') to type 'boost::launch'
    auto f_res = async(f,3);
                          ^
```

If I switch the commenting in the `#include` directuves and the `using` lines, and compile with

```
g++ -std=c++14 test_async_boost_2.cc -lpthread
```

I get the desired output:

```
in f 3
f 4
```

**How do I get `boost::async` to work with function arguments?**

And: Where do I find the reference documentation of `boos::async`?

Comment: [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/bind/bind.html)?

Comment: @Zereges: Doesn't that mean that the arguments have to be known at compile time?

Comment: @Zereges: Just tried it and it worked. Make it an answer please ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass a function with its arguments to the method accepting a function, you have to use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/bind/bind.html).